# Correct way to use MongoDB node.js `insertMany` so that it does not block

Tags: node.js, mongodb, async-await

Within a node.js application, I wanted to use `insertMany` to insert a lot of documents (well, actually, around 10'000). I encountered the following issue: While `insertMany` (called with `await`) is running, the node.js process is not processing anything from the processing loop until the `insertMany` call has finished.

Is this expected behaviour? How would I do this "the right way", so that my service would still process requests in the meantime? I would have expected the `await insertMany` to automatically enable this, as it's async, but it seems this is not the case.

Code snippet:

```
exports.writeOrg = async (req, res, next) => {
  logger.debug('orgs.writeOrg()');
  // ...
  try {
    // ...
    logger.debug('Starting processing of data.');
    const newOrgDocs = await processLdapUsers(tenantId, ldapUsers);
    logger.debug('Processing of data finished.');

    const orgModel = getOrgModel(tenantId);
    // Now delete the entire collection
    logger.debug(`Delete entire org collection in tenant ${tenantId}`);
    await orgModel.deleteMany({});
    // And add the new org information; this replaces what was there before
    logger.debug(`Inserting org structure to tenant ${tenantId}`);
    // This is the call which seems to block: --->
    await orgModel.insertMany(newOrgDocs);
    // <---
    logger.debug(`Finished inserting org structure to tenant ${tenantId}`);
    // ...
  } catch (err) {
    // ...
    // error handling
  }
}
```

The `writeOrg` function is a regular express request handler; the payload is a JSON array with typically 1000-20000 records; in the test case I have 6000 records with a total JSON size of around 6 MB. Writing locally takes just around 1.5s, writing to MongoDB Atlas (cheapest tier for testing) takes around 20 seconds, which is when this problem occurs.

**Workaround**: If I split up the data into smaller chunks, e.g. 50 records at a time, the event loop processes some data from time to time for other requests. But still, as the `insertMany` function is an `async` function call, I wasn't expecting this to be necessary.

Comment: plese show your code, where it is blocking

Comment: Added code and comment

Comment: How do you call this `writeOrg` function?

Comment: It's a pretty regular express handler; the payload data is uploaded to the service via gzipped JSON, but that _shouldn't_ make a difference. What's the reason for asking, I am really curious? Typical data size is something between 1 and 10 MB. In this case it's 6 MB of data in 6000 records, which is fine to handle in memory.

Comment: I believe that serializing the array into BSON to send to mongo is a synchronous operation, but I'd expect it to only be blocking while it's serializing but not while it's sending. Looking at event loop lag while uploading 100k items to atlas, and it blocked for about 4s (while serializing) but then the event loop freed up and was available even though the full upload took ~20 seconds

Comment: @willis Aha, okay, I didn't investigate that much, I was just noticing that it blocks for a substantial amount of time. It can very well be that it's the BSON serialization which blocks things for that long - my documents are about 6 MB, thus 10-15 seconds for the BSON serialization might look reasonable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple issues which make this rather slow, and the most important one is actually something which is not mentioned in the question: I am using **Mongoose** as an "ORM" wrapper for Mongo DB. I wasn't aware that this could have such a substantial impact on the runtime.

What happens here, after checking out the actual runtime with the Chrome node.js debugging tools, is that **Mongoose wraps and validates** each single document in the array, and this takes substantial time.

The BSON conversion also takes time, but the document wrapping is what takes up the most time.

This means: Mongoose is not super suitable for fast inserting (or reading, FWIW); if you need speed, going directly for the native Mongo DB driver is the way to go. If your needs for pure speed are not that big, and you want the convenience of Mongoose, Mongoose can add value by doing validations and adding defaults and things like that.